# WP7 Native code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

anybody tried running native code on WP7?  http://blog.walshie.me/2010/11/

every time i call Invoke() method

```
object o = dynMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { "Assembly.dll", new Guid("SomeGuidHere") });
```

o returns 2147942593.  I can't find a proper description for this code either.

any help highly appreciated.

Comment: 2147942593 = 0x800700c1  = ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I found this when i searched on google as well. All i wanted to know is how to make it work. Have you tried native call on WP7 ?

Comment: No, sorry, I just knew how to look up the error code for you: err.exe from the platform SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current incarnation of the platform, application developers (i.e. anyone not a device OEM) cannot write native code to run on Windows Phone devices.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, but see [this](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2012/02/leaked-windows-phone-8-vid-windows-8-kernel-and-integration-multiple-cores.ars). Claims Apollo will support 3rd party native code.

Also, [this](http://www.liveside.net/2012/01/28/windows-phone-tango-will-support-120-languages-c-development-support-coming-soon/). This claims even Tango will. (Tango=the next WP7 update, Apollo=the one after the next).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Waiting for WP8